# PHP special names - simple explanation needed

Tags: php

Can someone please explain the answers to the questions below? The answers were given by my lecturer; I don't know how to answer them myself.

**Consider the following code and complete the incomplete entries in the table:**

```php
<?php
   class Employee {
      private $name;

      function setName($name) { //<- LINE A
         if ($name == "") 
           echo "Name cannot be blank!";
         else 
           $this->name = $name;
      }

      function getName() { //<- LINE B
         return "My name is ".$this->name."<br />";
      }
   }

   class Executive extends Employee {
      function advertisingCompany() {
         echo "hi!";
      }
   }

   $exec = new Executive();//<- LINE C
   $exec->setName("Joe");
   echo $exec->getName();
   $exec->advertisingCompany();
?>
```

**Which feature of object-oriented programming is demonstrated by the above code?**
    *Inheritanc*

**What is the special name of the function as shown in LINE A?**
    *Mutator/setter*

**What is the special name of the function as shown in LINE B?**
    *Accessor/getter*

**What is the special name of the variable $exec as shown in LINE C?**
    *Object/instance*

**What will be the output of the above code?**

*My name is Joe 
Hi*

Comment: You have questions, you have answers. What's needed then?

Comment: I think you have answered all ans except there is typo in first ans it should be `Inheritance`

Comment: I have all the answers already, i need an explanation on how to get those answers as the answers have already been provided for me. I don't know how to answer them on my own.

Comment: http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/php-objects-page-1.php this is a good tutorial to get started with oops

Comment: You just need to learn object oriented fundamentals, and you'd be able to answer those. Have you done any procedural non-OOP or is this all new?

Comment: I'll go through the fundamentals now. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mutator/setter is a type of method that allows properties of an object to be modified (written).

An accessor/getter is a method that allows properties of an object to be accessed (read).

The reason for those two types of functions is that sometimes classes specify that properties are private or protected, and therefore inaccessible to outside code. You can access private or protected properties through getter/setter methods.

An object/instance is an actual live object created from a class.

The code runs two functions, one of which prints 'Hello my name is' and the other 'hi!'.